# Inserting hyphen between groups with Java regex issue

Tags: java, regex

I'm performing a test to find and replace a string of 3 or 4 capital letters followed by a number with that same string, a hyphen, and that same number. In Perl, I can use:

```
s/([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9])/$1-$2/g;
```

I've tried this in Java, hardcoding a string like:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "TEST1";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9])");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        if (m.find()) {
            m.replaceAll(m.group(1) + "-" + m.group(2));
        }
        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

But no match was found. Is my Java syntax wrong or is it a regular expression issue?

Comment: replaceAll returns a new String of your substitutions

Comment: If there is a method within the Matcher class called `replaceAll()`, what is its prototype?

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use Pattern/Matcher, you can just do:

```
test = test.replaceAll( "([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9])", "$1-$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher.replaceAll()` will return a String, not replace inline.

As seen here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Ah yes. Still, find() returns false so that's never even called

Comment: I tried your example, for me, the `find()`returns true and the replace is called properly. The regular expression is correct. Possibly you did a watch on `m.find()` in the debugger? This will modify the matcher and it will search the next match, which is not there, so subsequent calls return false.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a `replaceAll` with the regex you already have:

```
String test = "TEST1";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9])", "$1-$2"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vEXcUh)

This is from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> `public String replaceAll(String regex,
>                   String replacement)`
>   Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll 'replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string.'

You have matched on the entire input String and are replaceAll'ing it; you may as well create a new String from your matched groups.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class RegexTest {

    @Test
    public void regexReplaceSingleOccurance() {
        String test = "TEST1";
        String expectedOutput = "TEST-1";
        String replaceAllOutput = null;
        String concatenationOutput = null;

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9])");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        if (m.find()) {
            out = m.replaceAll(m.group(1) + "-" + m.group(2));
        }
        assertThat(replaceAllOutput, equalTo(expectedOutput));
        assertThat(concatenationOutput, equalTo(expectedOutput));
    }
}
```